# Fetch Object Only Returning 1 Value

Tags: php, pdo

Hi Guys I am having trouble on fetching object please see my code below.

Table Animals

```
-----------------------
id   |   type    | name
-----------------------
1      Cat         Muning
2      Kookaburra  Bruce
3      Dog         Bruce
-----------------------
```

Animal.php

```
class Animal extends DatabaseObject{

static $db_fields;
static $table_name = 'animals';

public function animal_group(){
global $database;

$sql = "SELECT animal_name as ani_name, COUNT(animal_name) as quantity FROM " . static::$table_name . " GROUP BY animal_name";


$stmt = $database->query($sql);
return $result = $database->fetch_object($stmt);
}

}

$animal = new Animal();
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once('includes/database.php');
require_once('includes/animal.php');
$ani = $animal->animal_group();

echo $ani->ani_name . " - " . $ani->quantity;
?>
```

Result

```
Bruce - 2
```

What it should be

```
Bruce - 2
Muning - 1
```

I also tried While and Foreach but still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are you using PDO?.
>
> Use fetchAll() instead of fetch_object.

Comment: Yes it worked but what I wanted is to call it like
$ani->ani_name instead of $ani['ani_name'] any suggestions? :)

Comment: $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "animal");

Answer (score 3):

`fetch_object` returns *one* row as an object. If you want to get all of them you have to call it in a loop, or otherwise use another method that returns all the rows from the result set (if you are using `mysqli`, that would be `fetch_all`).